# Export NgForm to Local Dynamic Variable in Angular 2

Tags: angular, dynamic-variables

I'm beginner in Angular 2/4. In my sample project, I trying to find out how to place multiple forms inside a for loop and associate each form with a dynamic variable. I had gone through multiple documentations and know that form can be associated with single static variable (#f) as:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of Collection; let i = index" #f="ngForm">
```

But i could not find anyway to create the variable dynamically, for ex.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of Collection; let i = index" #f{{i}}="ngForm">
```

Comment: What is your purpose? You can use the same name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Model Driven Forms, I suggest you use FormArray, it will make your life a lot easy.

https://plnkr.co/edit/clTbNP7MHBbBbrUp20vr?p=preview

```
     <div formArrayName="addresses">
          <div *ngFor="let address of myForm.controls.addresses.controls; let i=index" class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <span>Address {{i + 1}}</span>
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove pull-right" *ngIf="myForm.controls.addresses.controls.length > 1" (click)="removeAddress(i)"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body" [formGroupName]="i">
              <address [group]="myForm.controls.addresses.controls[i]"></address>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

In this example you can add as many address you want, which are basically a group of FormGroup

Check :
https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray
and:
https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-build-nested-model-driven-forms-in-angular-2

Comment: Thankyou!! This helped me.

Comment: Cool!! Glad to hear that